# Optimizing deletes from table using UDT (tsql)

Tags: sql

SQL Server.

I have a proc that takes a user defined table (readonly) and is about 7500 records large. Using that UDT, I run about 15 different delete statements:

```
delete from table1
where id in (select id from @table)

delete from table2
where id in (select id from @table)

delete from table3
where id in (select id from @table)

delete from table4
where id in (select id from @table)

....
```

This operation, as expected, does take a while (about 7-10 minutes). These columns are indexed. However, I suspect there is a more efficient way to do this. I know deletes are traditionally slower, but I wasn't expecting this slow.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could try disabling the indexes, carry out your deletes and then enable them back. http://www.lybecker.com/blog/2008/08/21/disable-and-enable-all-database-constraints/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test/try "exists" instead of "IN".  I really don't like IN clauses for anything besides casual lookup-queries. (Some people will argue about IN until they are blue in the face)

```
Delete deleteAlias
from table1 deleteAlias
where exists ( select null from @table vart where vart.Id = deleteAlias.Id )
```

You can populate a #temp table instead of a @variableTable.  Again, over the years, this has been trial and test it out.  @variable vs #temp , most of the time, doesn't make that big of a different.  But in about 4 situations I had, going to a #temp table made a big impact.
You can also experiment with putting an index on the #temp table (the "joining" column, 'Id' in this example )

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end


CREATE TABLE #Holder
(ID INT )


/* simulate your insert */
INSERT INTO #HOLDER (ID) 
select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4


/* CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_TempHolder_ID ON #Holder (ID) */
/* optional, create an index on the "join" column of the #temp table */  
CREATE INDEX IDX_TempHolder_ID ON #Holder (ID)


Delete deleteAlias
from table1 deleteAlias
where exists ( select null from #Holder holder where holder.Id = deleteAlias.Id )



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end
```

IMHO, there is not clear cut answer, sometimes you gotta experiment a little.

And "how your tempdb is setup' is a huge fork in the road that can affect #temp table performance.  But try the suggestions above first.

And one last experiment

```
Delete deleteAlias
from table1 deleteAlias
where exists ( select 1 from @table vart where vart.Id = deleteAlias.Id )
```

change the null to "1".... once I saw this affect something.  Weird, right?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will be experimenting.

Comment: I fixed the "not exists" to "exists".  If you find anything that helps, report back.  These situations are rare, so its good to have a documented "this actually helped" scenario.